# If $(y_{2n}-y_n) \to 0$ then $\lim_{n\to \infty} y_n$ exists

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Assume

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}  (y_{2n} - y_n)=0$$

then

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} y_n$$

exists.

I know it's not true, and I can see a sequence that disprove that $(1,1,2,1,3,2,4,1,5,3,...)$ but I want a sequence that has formula.

hint/help?

thanks

Comment: Why do you want a fancy formula? Just ASK for what you want.

Comment: If you really want a "formula," what about $\left\lceil \log_2(n)\right\rceil -\left\lfloor\log_2(n)\right\rfloor$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this one:

$y_n = 1$ if $n = 2^k$ for some integer $k$;

$y_n = 0$ otherwise.

In that case $y_{2n} - y_n = 0$ for all $n$. But $\lim_{n\to\infty} y_n$ does not exist.